# How to detect the end of a line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
def open_file(filename):
  data = open(filename, "r").read()
  return data
```

The file has two lines, so how can I detect where is line 1 and where is line 2?

Comment: Why not just read the first line, then read the second line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a string, you can split it by new line characters like so:

```
lines = data.splitlines()
```

To modify your original function to return this list of lines you could do something like:

```
def open_file(filename):
  file = open(filename, "r")
  lines = file.read().getlines()
  return lines
```

**Edit**

If you actually wanted to find the index at which the second like begins you could use `data.find("\n") + 1`, with the plus 1 being so that the the index is the character after the newline (i.e. the start of the second line).

Answer (score 0):

Use this function. It should return all the lines in list format.

```
def openfile(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        all_lines = f.readlines()
    return all_lines
```